# How to use "if" to handle with two xpath or more?

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I'm training web scraping with python through the code below.

But one of the data has two xpath, I would like to know if there is a way to capture both using an "if" condition, but I don't know how to insert it into my code. Can anyone guide me?

For example, if one of the xpath is null, it will surely be the other. I don't know if it was explained well, but if I have a and b, if a is null then b.

'vlr_atual' can be respectively:

```
product.xpath(".//span[@id='priceblock_ourprice']/text()").get()

product.xpath(".//span[@id='priceblock_saleprice']/text()").get()
```

https://www.amazon.com.br/Monitor-LG-19-5-LED-Inclina%C3%A7%C3%A3o/dp/B084TKF88Q/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&qid=1615682905&s=computers&sr=1-1

https://www.amazon.com.br/Monitor-Gamer-Dell-S2421HGF-23-8/dp/B086M269P3/ref=sr_1_19?dchild=1&qid=1615682905&s=computers&sr=1-19

```
import scrapy
import datetime

class ProductsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'products'
    allowed_domains = ['www.amazon.com.br']
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com.br/s?i=computers&bbn=16339926011&rh=n%3A16364756011&fs=true&qid=1615634908&ref=sr_pg_1']
    

    def parse(self, response):

        for produto in response.xpath("//div[@class='a-section a-spacing-medium']"):
            
            selo = produto.xpath(".//span[@class='a-badge-text']/text()").get()
            link = response.urljoin(produto.xpath(".//h2/a/@href").get())

            yield response.follow(url=link, callback=self.parse_details, meta={'selo' : selo})

        next_page = response.urljoin(response.xpath("//li[@class='a-last']/a/@href").get())
 
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_details(self, response):
        selo = response.request.meta['selo']
        for produto in response.xpath("//div[@id='dp']"):
            
            vlr_atual = produto.xpath(".//span[@id='priceblock_ourprice']/text()").get()
            if vlr_atual is None:
                 vlr_atual = produto.xpath(".//span[@id='priceblock_saleprice']/text()").get()
            yield{
                'data' : datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d"),
                'selo': selo,
                'nome': produto.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@id='productTitle']/text())").get(),
                'vlr_atual': vlr_atual,
                'estoque': produto.xpath("normalize-space(.//select[@name='quantity']/option[last()]/text())").get(),
                'ean': produto.xpath("normalize-space(.//table[@id='productDetails_techSpec_section_1']//tr[last()]/td/text())").get(),
            }
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?  You need to (1) fetch one path; (2) check to see whether it's null; (3) if not, use that path; (4) if so, use the other.  Each of these is a trivial step, no?

Comment: @Prune I'm stuck, because some products use the first xpath and some use the second xpath that I put in the question. Today I put on the first xpath and many products came out null. When I went to check it out, I realized it was products that used the second xpath. So I want a way to put a condition, if the first is null I get the second.

Comment: So how to you determine whether the first path is null?

Comment: @Prune I put the complete code, maybe it will be clearer. There are several products per page and I access the link for each one, but sometimes the price xpath varies. I found out by running the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something really simple:

```py
    def parse_details(self, response):
        selo = response.request.meta['selo']
        for produto in response.xpath("//div[@id='dp']"):

            # determine which field is vlr_atual
            ourprice = produto.xpath(".//span[@id='priceblock_ourprice']/text()").get()
            saleprice = produto.xpath(".//span[@id='priceblock_saleprice']/text()").get()
            if ourprice is not None:
                 vlr_atual = ourprice
            else:
                 vlr_atual = saleprice 

            yield {
                'data': datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d"),
                'selo': selo,
                'nome': produto.xpath("normalize-space(.//span[@id='productTitle']/text())").get(),
                'vlr_atual': vlr_atual,
                'estoque': produto.xpath("normalize-space(.//select[@name='quantity']/option[last()]/text())").get(),
                'ean': produto.xpath("normalize-space(.//table[@id='productDetails_techSpec_section_1']//tr[last()]/td/text())").get(),
            }
```

Comment: hi, i tried based on what you said, but don't get the answer i would like, some keep coming null, but thanks anyway

Comment: @LucasGuidi that sounds like for some responses "ourprice" and "saleprice" might both be missing? Perhaps you could put another condition in that `for` loop, and if both "ourprice" and "saleprice" are `None` - print the whole response and investigate the data. I can't do it because I'm not familiar with `scrapy` and don't know how this class is supposed to be run - perhaps you could add the missing code/command to the question?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [`or` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) to choose between two things while having a preference for the first one

```
>>> a="www.example.com"
>>> b="www.example2.com"
>>> a or b
'www.example.com'
>>> a=None
>>> a or b
'www.example2.com'
>>>
```

the way this work is that that if `a` have a ["truth"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) value of true then `a or b` return `a` otherwise it return `b`

so you can do

```
product.xpath (".//span[@id='priceblock_ourprice']/text()").get() or product.xpath (".//span[@id='priceblock_saleprice']/text()").get()
```

**Edit**

you can also encapsulate this into its own function, like so

```
def get_vlr_atual(product, default=None):
    lst_xpaths = [".//span[@id='priceblock_ourprice']/text()",
                 ".//span[@id='priceblock_saleprice']/text()"   
                ]
    for path in lst_paths:
        result = product.xpath(path).get()
        if result is not None:
            return result
    return default
```

this does basically the the same as before, but it can be easily be expanded to as many xpath as you like and if all of those fail just return some convenient default value

and simple use like

```
...
{...
  'vlr_atual': get_vlr_atual(product),
 ...
 }
...
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, but it's a little more advanced for me, I couldn't understand how I add it to the code, can you help me?

Comment: @LucasGuidi what is confusing you? the "..."? those stand for everything else in your sample code that I omitted for the sake of brevity, it basically mean search where in the dictionary you create that entry for 'vlr_atual' and assigned it the result of the function call `get_vlr_atual(product)`, and said function you put it somewhere appropriated in your code

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to use [Item Loaders](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html). You'll be able to automatically update selected fields in a single place. Take a first non blank value, join several results etc.
First define your `Product` in items.py with `TakeFirst` processor:

```
class ProductItem(scrapy.Item):
    
    data= scrapy.Field()
    selo = scrapy.Field()
    vlr_atual= scrapy.Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())
```

Next use it in you spider:

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
....

for produto in response.xpath("//div[@id='dp']"):
    l = ItemLoader(item=ProductItem(), selector=produto)
    l.add_value('data', datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d"))
    l.add_xpath("vlr_atual", ".//span[@id='priceblock_ourprice']/text()")
    l.add_xpath("vlr_atual", ".//span[@id='priceblock_saleprice']/text()")
    ...
    l.load_item()
```